# Error: Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference

Tags: perl

I am writing scripts where I have to pass or fail a test case. So I have some value in a variable which is coming out to be undef.

I am checking something like this:

I have a `$val` in which there are array of hashes. Now I am checking if that array is empty:

```
if(@$val<=0){do something}
```

So if that `$val = undef`, then this throws an error:

> Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference

How should I check if my `$val` is empty?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check if a scalar is undef, use the [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) operator.

```
if ( not defined $val ) { 
    # do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two parts to answering the question you might be asking.

First, unconditionally create the array reference.  If you might get passed `undef` in `$val`, promote it to an empty array reference in your code with something like `$val // []`.

Then, check to see if `@$val` is non-zero.  Non-zero-ness indicates that there are elements in the array.  Conventionally, this is phrased as a truth test:

```
unless (@{ $val // [] }) {
    ... # stuff to do if the array is empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
```

at the top of the file and they'll probably tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I am using it.. I get this error.. The thing is when I Dumper $val it is undef... so it is not able to reference it..

Comment: Show more of what you did then so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the "exists" function for this:
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html

This function checks whether your array reference exists in the array of hashes

```
    if(exists @$val<=0) {do something}
    else {print "$val is an undefined reference";}
```